# GADBanner error Stack Trace

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, stack-trace

It seems that I have a new error in my App update. This is a stack trace from Flurry Analytics. Any ideas what this means?

```
Full Stack Trace:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x1966fbbd0 _objc_msgSend + 16
1   Appname                             0x1002f3c28 -[GADBannerView slotFinishedLoadingAdContent:] + 220
2   Appname                             0x1002e3520 +[GADMacros runSynchronouslyOnMainThreadWithBlock:] + 64
3   Appname                             0x1002f3bb0 -[GADBannerView slotFinishedLoadingAdContent:] + 100
4   Appname                             0x1002f890c -[GADSlot adFinishedLoadingContent] + 56
5   Appname                             0x1002eefc0 -[GADBannerWebViewDelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:] + 548
6   Appname                             0x1003248c4 -[GADWebView webViewDidFinishLoad:] + 100
7   CoreFoundation                      0x1860b7df0 <redacted> + 144
8   CoreFoundation                      0x185fb665c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 296
9   CoreFoundation                      0x185fbb1f0 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 68
10  WebKitLegacy                        0x194835754 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 172
11  CoreFoundation                      0x1860b5c60 <redacted> + 440
12  CoreFoundation                      0x185fbb08c __CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
13  CoreFoundation                      0x1860b7df0 <redacted> + 144
14  CoreFoundation                      0x185fb665c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 296
15  WebCore                             0x1939ea8f4 <redacted> + 120
16  CoreFoundation                      0x18606a324 <redacted> + 24
17  CoreFoundation                      0x1860695c8 <redacted> + 264
18  CoreFoundation                      0x186067678 <redacted> + 712
19  CoreFoundation                      0x185f95664 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
20  GraphicsServices                    0x18f0cf5a4 _GSEventRunModal + 168
21  UIKit                               0x18a89a984 _UIApplicationMain + 1488
22  Appname                             0x10010cd0c -[MainRowType .cxx_destruct] + 180
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x196d56a08 <redacted> + 4
```

So the App is crashing by something the AdMob SDK does by itself?

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code and tell what iOS are you testing on ?>

Comment: well, my App is on the App Store and in use by thousands of people. The majority of them is obviously using iOS 8 (all different .x versions). I released an Update that was approved yesterday and now I get this new error. I didn t changed anything regarding AdMob so it s really strange, what I did change is that my App now uses backgrounding in opposite of before. I am not really good with stack trace reading and I thought someone here knows this error from using admob sdk... !? So no relevant code, just admob sdk normal implementation, reqquest ad, show ad... and no testing on specific iOS v.